# LTSpice Error from Unedited VOH1016 PSpice Model

Tags: ltspice, opto-isolator, pspice, error, pinout

I downloaded a PSpice model from Vishay for the VOH1016 optocoupler, and without modifying anything, I am getting a pin mismatch error. I opened the .lib file in LTSpice and automatically created the symbol with netlist. However, using it in the simplest circuit imaginable gives the following error:

"
WARNING: Can't resolve .param dpwr=$g_dpwr WARNING: Can't resolve .param dgnd=$g_dgnd Fatal Error: Port(pin) count mismatch between the definition of subcircuit "buf" and instance: "xu1:u2" The instance has more connection terminals than the definition.
"

I can't find much info about how the "Optional" tags in the .lib file, and I am very new to SPICE subckt directives in general, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

For reference, here is the .lib file:

```
* Library of High Speed Optocoupler VOH1016
* Copyright VISHAY, Inc. 2018 All Rights Reserved.
**
**
.SUBCKT VOH1016 A C NC VCC GND VO
dD1  A 6  DEMIT
vV1  6  C  DC 0
wW1  VCC 7  vV1  I_SW1
rR3  GND 7  10K  
xU2  7 VO $G_DPWR $G_DGND BUF
R4     0 NC 1MEG
C1     0 NC 1u
.MODEL DEMIT   D 
+ IS=1.8e-021 N=1.02e+000 RS=-8.406e-002
+ BV=3.000e+000 IBV=0.5e-006  XTI=4
+ EG=1.52436 CJO=18E-12 VJ=0.75 M=0.5 FC=0.5
.MODEL I_SW1 ISWITCH (Roff=1e6 Ron=1 IT=0.68m IH=0.12m TD=70ns)
.ENDS VOH1016
*$
***************************************************************
***-------------------------------------------------------------------------
**  1 INPUT BUFFER
**
.SUBCKT BUF  I0  O  optional: DPWR=$G_DPWR DGND=$G_DGND
U1 BUF DPWR  DGND I0  O 
+  D_PLD_GATE IO_PLD
.ENDS
*$
***-------------------------------------------------------------------------
.MODEL D_PLD_GATE  UGATE
*$
.MODEL D_PLD_TGATE  UTGATE
*$
.MODEL D_PLD_EFF  UEFF
*$
.MODEL D_PLD_GFF  UGFF
*$
.MODEL IO_PLD  UIO
*$
**==================================================================*
* Note:                                                             *
* Altough models can be a useful tool in evaluating device          *
* performance, they cannot model exact device performance           *
* under all conditions, nor are they intended to replace            *
* breadboarding for final verification!                             *
*                                                                   *
* Models provided by VISHAY Semiconductors GmbH are not             *
* as fully representing all of the specifications and operating     *
* characteristics of the semiconductor product to which the         *
* model relates.                                                    *
* The models describe the characteristics of typical devices.       *
* In all cases, the current data sheet information for a given      *
* device is the final design guideline and the only actual          *
* performance specification.                                        *
* VISHAY Semiconductors does not assume any liability arising       *
* from the model use. VISHAY Semiconductors reserves the right to   *
* change models without prior notice.                               *
**==================================================================*
```

from this site: https://www.vishay.com/en/product/84896/tab/designtools-ppg/

and here is the circuit:
[image]
Thanks!

*****EDIT*****
I was able to find a different model at https://github.com/kicad-spice-library/KiCad-Spice-Library/blob/master/Models/uncategorized/Bordodynovs%20Electronics%20Lib/sub/LT__VOH1016.lib

Additionally, I had VO and GND flipped on the attached screenshot.

Comment: I don't think "optional:" is supported by LTspice. Also, $G_DPWR  and $G_DGND probably aren't known netnames, though I'm not sure about the optional syntax, either. But it looks as though their use of the BUF subckt would allow simple removal of the syntax and just using the two extra pins on the definition line. So it appears to be solvable.

Comment: I agree with the above.  Best thing to do would be to get rid of their proprietary buffer and replace it with something else.  Either an opamp buffer or an E-source or even one of LTspice's proprietary digital gate buffers.  Check this reference out:  https://groups.io/g/LTspice/topic/50263035

Comment: Check this out too:  https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/_GLOBAL_Declare_global_nodes.htm

Comment: @periblepsis Thanks! I did not know there were proprietary features like this in PSpice models.

Comment: @SteKulov Thanks for the links! The first one had a Yahoo link that was broken, but I did find another model at the edited link above.

Comment: The ISWITCH in there is also proprietary, but LTspice knows how to (behind the scenes) modify its parameters and map it to a W-SWITCH.  These `UGATE`'s are a different story and require manual correction.  Ideally, a model author wouldn't use any of these for maximum compatibility.  Also, keep in mind that the `LT__VOH1016.lib` will only work in LTspice and no other SPICE software since the UGATE was replaced by an `A-device` which is proprietary to LTspice.